# ¿Como generar un datepicker desde un fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, datepicker

Necesito crear generar un date picker desde un fragmento, el problema es que los datepicker que e visto (ejemplos) son generados a partir de una Activity, y resulta que para los fragment no es iggual, necesito almacenar un periodo de tiempo y en el fragment poseo 2 `button` y 2 `textview` un `button` y un `textview` para el inicio de la fecha y los restante para la culminacion de la misma estos text view luego seran almacenados en la base de datos de forma `integer`... pero ya eso es otra cosa...

mi objetivo es:

generar el data picker en el fragment

obtener una fecha de inicio y una fecha de cierre (es decir un periodo de tiempo) (en cada boton respectivamente existe un TextView que se cargara esas fechas)

**ConfiguracionPeriodoF.java** (este es el fragment)

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.icu.util.TimeZone;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

import static android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;


public class ConfiguracionPeriodoF extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // mandamos a cargar la imagen del fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuracion_periodo, container, false);

        //creamos las variables que van a interactuar con el layout
        //TextView
        TextView inifecha = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fechaini);
        TextView finalfecha = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fechafinal);
        //botones
        Button btnini = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfragfecha);
        Button btnfinal = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfragfinal);


        return view;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**fragment_configuracion_periodo.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionPeriodoF">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Inserte periodo de trabajo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etnombreperiodo"
            android:hint="Nombre del periodo a insertar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="Inicio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnfragfecha"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fechaini"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="Final"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnfragfinal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fechafinal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:text="Agregar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/agregarperiodo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Editar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editarperiodo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Para poder implementar los `DatePicker` debes utilizar `DialogFragment` que implemente la funcion de `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: ¿como podría hacerlo? ¿podrías decirme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fácil... lo que debes es implementar esto en tu onclick del fragmento correspondiente a la fecha que quieras capturar ( es decir uno para cada boton solo modifica el la variables correspondiente para el segundo boton...

```
final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
int yy = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mm = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int dd = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

     String fecha = String.valueOf(year) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                            +"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
     inifecha.setText(fecha);

    }
}, yy, mm, dd);

datePicker.show();
```

Comment: como funciona? podrías guiarme mas?

Comment: @ERnyJOséHIdalgoCOrrea en este enlace esta la información completa, esta en ingles, pero el codigo es completamente entendible espero pueda ayudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923604/implementing-datepicker-in-fragment

Comment: no seria novedad que no soy muy diestro con esto ( estoy de auto estudio) y que el ingles no se me da muy bien, intente exactamente esa alternativa pero algo dañe, podria invitarte aun chat para que me puedas guiar?

Comment: @ERnyJOséHIdalgoCOrrea si!

Comment: ok, ahora a ver como hago eso xD no se nunca me deja generarlo solo te llamo con el @ a ver si puedo

Comment: wow no se hacer un chat, podriamos entrar a este.. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51558/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-acr que esta sin usar

Comment: Por favor, provee más información en la respuesta. Tal como está redactada, luce más como un comentario.

Comment: @ERnyJOséHIdalgoCOrrea mándame un mail aaronzadev@gmail.com, en el chat ya no pude responderte

Comment: PERFECTO! asi era

Answer (score 0):

Realiza algunos cambios.

```
public class ConfiguracionPeriodoF extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // mandamos a cargar la imagen del fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuracion_periodo, container, false);

        //creamos las variables que van a interactuar con el layout
        //TextView
        TextView inifecha = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fechaini);
        TextView finalfecha = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fechafinal);
        //botones
        Button btnini = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfragfecha);
        Button btnfinal = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfragfinal);


        return view;
    }


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnfragfecha:
                obtenerFecha();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Llama esta función en tu evento clic del botón **btnini**  por ejemplo.

```
public void obtenerFecha(){

        final int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final int anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                int mesActual = month + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10)? "0" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth):String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10)? "0" + String.valueOf(mesActual):String.valueOf(mesActual);

                inifecha.setText(diaFormateado + "/" + mesFormateado +"/"+ year);

            }
        },anio, mes, dia);

        recogerFecha.show();

    }
```

Listo así obtendrás la fecha actual, espero que le sirva.